# we are getting permissions issue while running api (Youtube Analytics API) from the website

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

When we are running youtube Analytics API(**Youtube Analytics API Request Query**) from website to get specific channel information, we are getting permission issue "**You do not have permission to execute this method**".

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: can any one suggest how to fix the issue

Comment: Can you add your code you have so we can help you?

Comment: @SHOContent You can't use it for anyone's channel. You can try the channel of the user which is authorize in your app.

Answer (score 0):

[Reports: Query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reference/reports/query) clearly states at the top:

> All YouTube Analytics API requests **must be authorized**.
>  The Authorization guide explains how to use the OAuth 2.0 protocol to retrieve authorization tokens.
>   YouTube Analytics API requests use the following **authorization** scopes:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly View
>   YouTube Analytics reports for your YouTube content. This scope
>   provides access to user activity metrics, like view counts and rating
>   counts.
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly    View
>   YouTube Analytics monetary reports for your YouTube content. This
>   scope provides access to user activity metrics and to earnings and ad
>   performance metrics. 
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube  Manage
>   your YouTube account. In the YouTube Analytics API, channel owners use
>   this scope to manage YouTube Analytics groups and group items.
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner    View and manage YouTube
>   assets and associated content on YouTube. In the YouTube Analytics
>   API, content owners use this scope to manage YouTube Analytics groups
>   and group items.

To fix your problem [authorize](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication) your requests as it says in the documentation.

Comment: we are running this from the website.

we have authorized the request
but still we are getting the issue **"You do not have permission to execute this method"**